# Presenting UIDocumentInteractionController with UIViewControllerRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, swiftui

I'm creating a new iOS app using SwiftUI where ever possible. However, I want to be able to generate a PDF with some data.
In a similar project without swiftUI I can do this

```
let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: "PATH_TO_FILE")
                        docController.delegate = self
                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                            docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
                        })
```

and as long as somewhere else in the view controller I have this:

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
```

I'm good to go.
What I can't work out is how to apply this to a UIViewControllerRepresentable and have it working in SwiftUI. Should my UIViewControllerRepresentable be aiming to be a UIViewController? How do I then set the delegate and presentPreview? Will this overlay any view and display full screen over my SwiftUI app as it does for my standard iOS app?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is possible approach to integrate `UIDocumentInteractionController` for usage from SwiftUI view.

[image: demo]

Full-module code. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct DocumentPreview: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    private var isActive: Binding<Bool>
    private let viewController = UIViewController()
    private let docController: UIDocumentInteractionController

    init(_ isActive: Binding<Bool>, url: URL) {
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPreview>) -> UIViewController {
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPreview>) {
        if self.isActive.wrappedValue && docController.delegate == nil { // to not show twice
            docController.delegate = context.coordinator
            self.docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordintor {
        return Coordintor(owner: self)
    }
    
    final class Coordintor: NSObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate { // works as delegate
        let owner: DocumentPreview
        init(owner: DocumentPreview) {
            self.owner = owner
        }
        func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return owner.viewController
        }
        
        func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
            controller.delegate = nil // done, so unlink self
            owner.isActive.wrappedValue = false // notify external about done
        }
    }
}

// Demo of possible usage
struct DemoPDFPreview: View {
    @State private var showPreview = false // state activating preview

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Preview") { self.showPreview = true }
                .background(DocumentPreview($showPreview, // no matter where it is, because no content
                            url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf")!))
        }
    }
}

struct DemoPDFPreview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoPDFPreview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally got round to testing this, works absolutely great. Thank you!

Comment: Quick other question, any thoughts with this similar one Asperi? Thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424672/how-to-present-a-uicollectionview-in-swiftui-with-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

Comment: @Asperi, for me its opening twice and dismissing after 2 times click. Any solution?

Comment: When clicking done, the view reappears. Clicking done a second time dismissed appropriately. The update is being called before the end preview.

Comment: This also complains about the view not being presented on the stack

Comment: Just retested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14 - works fine.

Comment: @Asperi Is it possible to dynamically pass the URL in the above code snippet? I have a use case where I get the dynamic URL via a network request and I need to construct the Preview. The view controller's view isn't added to the window hierarchy by the time the preview is shown and hence the view is blank and transparent.

Comment: @Asperi My apologies, I got the logic working on my end. I just have one confusion. In order for this to work, why do we have to add the `DocumentPreview` view as the background of the button in this case? Why does the view not work when added to the `VStack` as an independent view?

Comment: I have the same problem. After the first dismiss it will show again. The real dismiss occurs only after the second dismiss. Any updates on this?

Comment: I have Thread 1: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]"

Answer (score 6):

I ended up doing something like the following as I wasn't able to get this working reliably with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and the above answer. You might need to edit / extend this for your usecase.

```swift
class DocumentController: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    func presentDocument(url: URL) {
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.url = url
        controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
struct DocumentView: View {
  @StateObject var documentController = DocumentController()

  var body: some View {
      Button(action: {
          documentController.presentDocument(url: ...)
      }, label: {
          Text("Show Doc")
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this in iPhone 12 iOS 16, it doesn't present the view.

Comment: `'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead`

Comment: `return (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { ($0 as UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }.last?.rootViewController)!` fixes it

Answer (score 3):

### Using `QLPreviewController`

I know the question is about **UIDocumentInteractionController**, but if you want to present a `PDF file` (for example), you can use a **[QLPreviewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller)**.

#### Local file

Presenting a local file:

[image: Show Local File]

```
import SwiftUI

struct DocView: View {
    @State private var buttonPressed: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            buttonPressed = true
        } label: {
            Text("Show PDF file")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $buttonPressed) {
            let localURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Example", withExtension: "pdf")!
            PreviewController(url: localURL)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Remote file

Please [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/Enriquecm/43ad7ed40dafdcaa51001a7a07f1def4) if you need to present a remote file.

[image: Show Remote File]

#### PreviewController

The UIViewControllerRepresentable for `QLPreviewController`.

```swift
import QuickLook
import SwiftUI

struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(context.coordinator.dismiss)
        )

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let parent: PreviewController

        init(parent: PreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func previewController(
            _ controller: QLPreviewController,
            previewItemAt index: Int
        ) -> QLPreviewItem {
            return parent.url as NSURL
        }

        @objc func dismiss() {
            parent.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with the accepted answer - the view would show twice. All I had to do is to to reset self.isActive:

```
        if self.isActive.wrappedValue && docController.delegate == nil { // to not show twice
            self.isActive.wrappedValue = false // add this!
```