# UICollectionView wrapped for SwiftUI breaks scroll animation (UIViewControllerRepresentable)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicollectionview

In our app we have an infinite (vertical) scroll where we need pagination (snapping to cells - of different heights), as this seemed to be very tedious to implement with SwiftUI, we used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mattadatta/667fe7f8f176dda2a9cf99c635eb4c55) that wraps a `UICollectionView` with a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Since the scroll is infite, further data is appended to the initial data once the user reaches almost the end.

This all works well, except: **when the data array gets updated, the scrolling animation (either the snapping or normal scroll) stops at once, without finishing the animation.** This also happens when updating the data using `withAnimation`:

```swift
withAnimation {
     // update data
}
```

My suspicion is that this is due to the way the `UICollectionView` is wrapped since when using the normal `ScrollView` of SwiftUI it all works fine.

How can I insert data to the UICollectionView without breaking the scrolling animation? Or is there a better way to wrap it than with the gist linked?

P.S. using some complex SwiftUI solution is also not ideal since we need a custom Scroll to refresh functionality, which would make things even more complex in SwiftUI but has been implemented very easily with the Representable.

MRE (source of wrapper: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mattadatta/667fe7f8f176dda2a9cf99c635eb4c55)):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
}

class PostService: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts: [Model] = []
    
    init() {
        self.posts = [Model(), Model(), Model()]
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            print("adding data")
            self.addData()
        }
    }
    
    func addData() {
        Task { // this is because in the real example there are async calls in here...
            let newData = Model()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation {
                    self.pooledPosts.append(newData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var postService: PostService
    
    var body: some View {
          CollectionView(
                            collection: postService.posts,
                            scrollDirection: .vertical,
                            contentSize: .crossAxisFilled(mainAxisLength: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100),
                            itemSpacing: .init(mainAxisSpacing: 0, crossAxisSpacing: 0),
                            rawCustomize: { collectionView in
                                collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
                                //collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
                                // no matter what this is set to the issue is present
                            },
                            contentForData: MyCustomCell.init)
    }
}

struct MyCustomCell : View {
    
    let data: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(self.data.id)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: 0x000000))
                .fontWeight(.black)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(14))
    }
}

struct CollectionView
    <Collections, CellContent>
    : UIViewControllerRepresentable
    where
    Collections : RandomAccessCollection,
    Collections.Index == Int,
    Collections.Element : RandomAccessCollection,
    Collections.Element.Index == Int,
    Collections.Element.Element : Identifiable,
    CellContent : View
{
    
    typealias Row = Collections.Element
    typealias Data = Row.Element
    typealias ContentForData = (Data) -> CellContent
    typealias ScrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection
    typealias SizeForData = (Data) -> CGSize
    typealias CustomSizeForData = (UICollectionView, UICollectionViewLayout, Data) -> CGSize
    typealias RawCustomize = (UICollectionView) -> Void
    
    enum ContentSize {
        
        case fixed(CGSize)
        case variable(SizeForData)
        case crossAxisFilled(mainAxisLength: CGFloat)
        case custom(CustomSizeForData)
    }
    
    struct ItemSpacing : Hashable {
        
        var mainAxisSpacing: CGFloat
        var crossAxisSpacing: CGFloat
    }
    
    fileprivate let collections: Collections
    fileprivate let contentForData: ContentForData
    fileprivate let scrollDirection: ScrollDirection
    fileprivate let contentSize: ContentSize
    fileprivate let itemSpacing: ItemSpacing
    fileprivate let rawCustomize: RawCustomize?

    init(
        collections: Collections,
        scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .vertical,
        contentSize: ContentSize,
        itemSpacing: ItemSpacing = ItemSpacing(mainAxisSpacing: 0, crossAxisSpacing: 0),
        rawCustomize: RawCustomize? = nil,
        contentForData: @escaping ContentForData)
    {
        self.collections = collections
        self.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
        self.contentSize = contentSize
        self.itemSpacing = itemSpacing
        self.rawCustomize = rawCustomize
        self.contentForData = contentForData
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(view: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let coordinator = context.coordinator
        let viewController = ViewController(coordinator: coordinator, scrollDirection: self.scrollDirection)
        coordinator.viewController = viewController
        self.rawCustomize?(viewController.collectionView)
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        // TODO: Obviously we can be efficient about what needs to be updated here
        context.coordinator.view = self
        uiViewController.layout.scrollDirection = self.scrollDirection
        self.rawCustomize?(uiViewController.collectionView)
        uiViewController.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension CollectionView {
    
    /*
     Convenience init for a single-section CollectionView
     */
    init<Collection>(
        collection: Collection,
        scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .vertical,
        contentSize: ContentSize,
        itemSpacing: ItemSpacing = ItemSpacing(mainAxisSpacing: 0, crossAxisSpacing: 0),
        rawCustomize: RawCustomize? = nil,
        contentForData: @escaping ContentForData) where Collections == [Collection]
    {
        self.init(
            collections: [collection],
            scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
            contentSize: contentSize,
            itemSpacing: itemSpacing,
            rawCustomize: rawCustomize,
            contentForData: contentForData)
    }
}

extension CollectionView {
    
    fileprivate static var cellReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "HostedCollectionViewCell"
    }
}

extension CollectionView {

    final class ViewController : UIViewController {

        fileprivate let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView

        init(coordinator: Coordinator, scrollDirection: ScrollDirection) {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
            self.layout = layout
            
            let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            collectionView.backgroundColor = nil
            collectionView.register(HostedCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
            collectionView.dataSource = coordinator
            collectionView.delegate = coordinator
            self.collectionView = collectionView
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("In no way is this class related to an interface builder file.")
        }

        override func loadView() {
            self.view = self.collectionView
        }
    }
}

extension CollectionView {
    
    final class Coordinator : NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        
        fileprivate var view: CollectionView
        fileprivate var viewController: ViewController?

        init(view: CollectionView) {
            self.view = view
        }
        
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return self.view.collections.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.view.collections[section].count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HostedCollectionViewCell
            let data = self.view.collections[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
            let content = self.view.contentForData(data)
            cell.provide(content)
            return cell
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = cell as! HostedCollectionViewCell
            cell.attach(to: self.viewController!)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = cell as! HostedCollectionViewCell
            cell.detach()
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            switch self.view.contentSize {
            case .fixed(let size):
                return size
            case .variable(let sizeForData):
                let data = self.view.collections[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
                return sizeForData(data)
            case .crossAxisFilled(let mainAxisLength):
                switch self.view.scrollDirection {
                case .horizontal:
                    return CGSize(width: mainAxisLength, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
                case .vertical:
                    fallthrough
                @unknown default:
                    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: mainAxisLength)
                }
            case .custom(let customSizeForData):
                let data = self.view.collections[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
                return customSizeForData(collectionView, collectionViewLayout, data)
            }
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return self.view.itemSpacing.mainAxisSpacing
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return self.view.itemSpacing.crossAxisSpacing
        }
    }
}

private extension CollectionView {
    
    final class HostedCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
        
        var viewController: UIHostingController<CellContent>?

        func provide(_ content: CellContent) {
            if let viewController = self.viewController {
                viewController.rootView = content
            } else {
                let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
                hostingController.view.backgroundColor = nil
                self.viewController = hostingController
            }
        }
        
        func attach(to parentController: UIViewController) {
            let hostedController = self.viewController!
            let hostedView = hostedController.view!
            let contentView = self.contentView
            
            parentController.addChild(hostedController)
            
            hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(hostedView)
            hostedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            hostedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            hostedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            hostedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            
            hostedController.didMove(toParent: parentController)
        }
        
        func detach() {
            let hostedController = self.viewController!
            guard hostedController.parent != nil else { return }
            let hostedView = hostedController.view!
            
            hostedController.willMove(toParent: nil)
            hostedView.removeFromSuperview()
            hostedController.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. Linking to an external website, even a Gist does not qualify - the [mcve] has to be included in the body of your question.

Comment: I figured it is simply too much to place the entire gist in here, but I will do so anyway in that case..

Comment: If it is way too much code, then most probably it isn't a [mcve]. Try removing as much code as possible until you are left with the _minimal_ code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DávidPásztor fair enough.. I added the MRE, though cannot test it right now, there might be typos.. Will correct it when I can use my normal setup in a few hours

Comment: I think that gist has not implemented `UIViewControllerRepresentable` correctly, it shouldn't call `uiViewController.collectionView.reloadData()` inside `updateUIViewController`. Also `Coordinator(view: self)` is known to be bad. Perhaps try and find another wrapper.

Comment: @malhal interesting, thanks for the heads up.. The problem is that I also need to pass data and that I want to use SwiftUI views again as cells, so I didn't find much out there. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558704/9739903) (without these two requirements) and [this](https://github.com/michzio/SwifUICollectionView) but I wouldn't know how to implement my requirements.. the second one having the same _"problems"_ that you mentioned...

Comment: @malhal I just found [this example project](https://github.com/shabib87/SwiftUICollectionView) to [this blog post](https://www.codewithshabib.com/how-to-create-a-swiftui-collectionview/). Since I am not experienced I cannot tell if this is the right way to implement this, what do you think?

Comment: Update: Upon further searching I also found [this](https://github.com/defagos/SwiftUICollection). I will be trying out this and the one from my last comment soon..

Comment: No to the most recent one, the items should be Identifiable not Hashable.